# Repeater Vs String Builder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I think the question may seem a little weird, but here's the details.

**The Goal :** To retrieve a set of pairs (text, value) for various reasons. one example for that of them is retrieving the alphabet, each letter will be used as an anchor or a LinkButton, the text value will be the letter and the click event will take the value part of the pair and place it in a stringFormat() to form a "Parametrized URL"

*I've used two approaches for this goal but I don't know which is better!*

**1. Using a Repeater**

A repeater that will have a LinkButton in it's ItemTemplate and through this blocks and will set the text to the 'text' and using eval and the 'value' to create the QueryString.

**2. Using StringBuilder**

Create an instance of StringBuilder
Use a loop with a counter equal to the total pairs to be retrieved. and append a certain string format that will build a long string with all the needed anchors for navigation using some code like this

```
Links_strngBuilder.Append(string.Format("<a href='/data.aspx?page={0}'>{0}</a>", chrctr))
```

and finally convert the String Builder instance to a string and assign it to a label

*Note: the chrctr text and value fields will be retrieved as you suggest [in each loop from the database] or [loaded in an array/arrayList/List<> to store the values and save all those connections to the db]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where i work we will never use a stringbuild becouse of the designer. We dont want the designer in the codebehind if he has to make a simple change. so keep the markup in the view and codebehind in the codebehind.

**Edit**

Other advantage of repeater is the change of cycle is much easier. No need to recompile and perhaps redeploy the tweak the UI, just edit the ASPX template, save and refresh.

Comment: +1 yh you're right, StringBuilder will keep things complicated. but I was looking for a complete comparison or at least the most important points like performance and scalability.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about how these two approaches perform (in terms of memory usage and speed) comparing to each other but I'd definitely go for Repeater because:

- The code is much easier to understand & **support**
- Using a StringBuilder reminds me the days of the classic ASP when the Response.Write was used widely.
- You can't use any of the benefits of the Visual Designer with a StringBuilder.

-- Pavel

Comment: pretty the same answer as Kim but more detailed, Thanks! +1. still hoping for a little more details about the PROS and CONS for each approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think building the output fits more in client side(e.g. when you do an ajax call and want to show the results in html) than server side except when your build a custom server control.

In addition, if you use the repeater you have the extensibility option whenever requirements changed, and you have more control and facilities(like event handling and styling with css and so forth).